# How to map class fields to another class?

Tags: java

I'm not looking for the *best* way to do this, but rather for *any* way to do what i need while adhering to the DRY principle.

Let's say I have a class `Source` as follows. `Source` contains thirty strings.

```
class Source {
    private String sourceAttrOne = "sourceValueOne";
    private String sourceAttrTwo = "sourceValueTwo";
    ...
    private String sourceAttrThirty = "sourceValueThirty";
}
```

This information is to be used to create a new object of class `Destination`. 25 of `Destination`'s attributes have a name in a similar format (but not the *same* name). 10 of these are Strings, while 5 are Dates, and 5 are Integers. The last 5 fields, however, are totally different.

```
class Destination {
    private String AttrOne;
    ...
    private Date AttrSixteen;
    ...
    private Integer AttrTwentyOne;
    ...
    // Last 5 fields are different
    private SomeOtherClass someOtherName;
    private TheBestClass imAlsoSpecial;

    // Standard getters and setters
}
```

For the 25 "normal" attributes, I need to use a helper method to get from the source value to the result. The helper method used depends on the destination type:

```
destination.setAttrOne(getResultingString(source.getSourceAttrOne()));
destination.setAttrSixteen(getResultingDate(source.getSourceAttrSixteen());
destination.setAttrSeventeen(getResultingDate(source.getSourceAttrSeventeen()/*, custom Date format for AttrSeventeen */));
```

The remaining 5 attributes need custom (individual) logic.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated, I don't need a complete solution :)

Comment: First of all don't have twenty five different `String`'s and corresponding methods to access them. Put them in a data structure such as a `List`

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for a way to dynamically assign the value for the last **"special"** variables? And they are not Strings?

Comment: @GBlodgett I agree that this question makes it seem like that would be a better approach. However, I would argue that this is a result of me trying to simplify the question as much as possible. In reality using a list instead is not an option :/

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich None of the special variables are Strings, Dates, or similar. I have no preference as to whether the special ones are assigned dynamically or not

Comment: Hmm, feels like you want some method like `<T> T getValue(String value, Formatter<T> formatter)`. Then for different formats you can create different implementations. On the other hand you could also use formatter directly, or create more helper methods like in your example. What is the exact goal you want to achieve?

Comment: @IgorNikolaev The goal is to construct a `Destination` object. I have a method that takes a `Source` object as an argument, fetches some other relevant information, and uses this to construct then return the finished `Destination` object.

Comment: That I understand, what I meant is why approach similar to using `getResultingDate` doesn't work for custom fields?

Comment: The complications are: 1. the custom fields needs information from more than one of the strings 2. the resulting value in custom fields sometimes depend on values in other fields

Answer (score 1):

**N.B.:** I'm probably totally mistaken, so nevermind me if that's the case. 
I also haven't unlocked comments yet, while it would be more likely the best; sorry for the inconvenience.

---

If the 1st to 15th attributes are String, then supposedly, you can simply affect them to the corresponding attributes, or clone them first, if you prefer.

For the 16th to 21th(?), which are dates, you might be able to use [*DateFormat's parse(String)*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) method; although, I'm clueless on how to help the compiler to get the used format or if it can do it properly by itself.

For the 22th to 27th(?), the Integers, you should be able to use [*Integer's parse(String)*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) method, or possibly through *Double's* and then convert back to an Integer or an int.

Comment: There's no harm in trying to help out :) This would still require 25 lines of very similar code right? I was looking for something more elegant, where I could just write a few lines of code and have all the similar attributes mapped automagically

Comment: Well, I'm not experienced enough to know whether there is a method to do that; but if there is, I'm interested in it.

Anyway, thank you. :)

Comment: Maybe you could use a `switch ... case` structure with a specific logic, or use a special structure such as a *Set* or a *Tree* class, but you said that you aren't able to use structures like lists, so I guess it's not the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Reflection for similar targets.
Something like:

```
public void fillFieldsHelper(Object source) {

List<Field> sourceFields = source.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

or

Field valueOne = source.getClass().getDeclaredField("sourceAttrOne");

System.out.println(valueOne.getName());
System.out.println(valueOne.getType());

...

Object value = valueOne.get(source);
Field attrOne = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(valueOne.getName().replace("source",""));

switch (attrOne.getType().getName()) {
 case "java.lang.Integer":
  attrOne.set(this, Integer.valueOf(value));
  break;
 default: 
  attrOne.set(this, value);
}
...

etc.
```

I can't say that Reflection is elegant but it's useful in many cases.

Comment: thanks, I was looking at that, but I couldn't figure out quite how to overcome the problem of none of the attribute names matching exactly, and the fact that I need different helper methods depending on the attribute type in the destination. If you got any ideas I'm all ears :)

Comment: You can use two maps for each pair of classes: one for matching fields and another for matching data types. Something like: "sourceValueOne" to "AttrOne" and "java.lang.String" to "java.lang.Integer". With help of diffirent maps and an universal helper you can map classes in your app, as variant.

Comment: hmm, seems like it could work, although as you said, not the most elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So in your case you have several possibilities.

1. Create Object from Object

The easiest but maybe not the nicest solution (depending on your further process/requirements) is to have a constructer which has the need Object as parameter.

```
public class Source {
    private String sourceAttrOne;
    private String sourceAttrTwo;
    // further class attributes....

    // getters (& setters)
}

public class Destination {
    private String attrOne;
    private String attTwo;

    public Destination(Source source) {
        this.attrOne = source.getSourceAttrOne;
        this.attrTwo = source.getSourceAttrTwo;
        // etc..
    }
}
```

1. User Builder Pattern

The problem in the solution above is, that depending of which fields are required for creating the `Destination.class` the constructer is going to have a lot of parameters. In addition, if you have to change your constructer in the future (e.g. additional required fields), you have to create a new constructer or change the already existing one (which implies you have to change all the current usages of that).
Therefore to hold the DRY, I would recommend the Builder Patter.

```
public class Destination {
    private String attrOne;
    private String attTwo;
    private String attThree; // attribute which comes not from any other source class and is e.g. not a required field

    private Destination() {
        // should not be accessible 
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private String attrOne;
        private String attTwo;
        private String attThree;

        private Builder() {
            // do nothing
        }

        public static Builder create(Source source) {
            Builder builder = new Builder();

            builder.attrOne = source.getSourceAttrOne();
            builder.attrTwo = source.getSourceAttrTwo();

            return builder;
        }

        public Builder attThree(String attThree) {
            this.attThree = attThree;
            return this;
        } 

        public Destination build() {
            Destination destination = new Destination();

            destination.attrOne = builder.attrOne;
            destination.attrTwo = builder.attrTwo;
            destination.attrThree = builder.attrThree;

            //add several validations e.g. assert destination.attrOne != null

            return destination;
        }
    }
}
```

To create a `Destination.class` with `Source.class` you can do following:

```
Destination.Builder.create(source).build();
```

For having different Types e.g. `Source.sourceAttrOne` is a String and the in the `Destination.attrOne` is a Date, you just have to adjust the `Destination.class`.

```
public class Destination {
    private LocalDate attrOne;
    // ...

    private Destination() {}

    public static class Builder {
        private String attrOne;
        // ...

        private Builder() {}

        public static Builder create(Source source) {
            Builder builder = new Builder();

            builder.attrOne = LocalDate.parse(source.getSourceAttrOne());
            // ...

            return builder;
        }

        public Destination build() {
            Destination destination = new Destination();

            destination.attrOne = builder.attrOne;
            // ...

            return destination;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate you taking the time write this up. One question though - The helper methods used to "convert" the source strings into the destination object (e.g. `getResultingString`) exist in another method. Would you suggest moving these into the `Destination` class, and just pass the required parameters when building?

Comment: that really depends on what the helper methods (eg. 'getResultingString') do. if they generic you can use that helper within multiple builder, if they are really specific to one builder, i would put the method into the builder